# Strange behavior of grapheme_strlen function with some line endings

Tags: php, string, unicode, icu, intl

Can anyone explain this weird behavior of the Unicode `strlen` function in PHP's intl extension?

```
var_dump(grapheme_strlen("a\r\n")); // (ASCII 'a') length: 3
var_dump(grapheme_strlen("の\r\n")); // length: 2
var_dump(grapheme_strlen("\r\n")); // length: 2
```

Seems like `grapheme_strlen` is counting "\r\n" (CR LF, which are two separate code points used for line separation on Windows) as a single grapheme, which could be quite reasonable considering the name of the function, but it does it **only** if the line ending is preceded by a non-ASCII character. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. `grapheme_strlen` should work on the Grapheme Cluster Boundaries defined in [Unicode Standard Annex #29 (Unicode Text Segmentation)](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Grapheme_Cluster_Table). The standard clearly says not to break between CR and LF.

If you have a look at the PHP source, `grapheme_strlen` simply [returns the number of characters](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/d23111197240849324bde644a02efc8cd9492fbf/ext/intl/grapheme/grapheme_string.c#L72) for ASCII strings.

Comment: Would anyone file a bug report?